# What's the best practice: HTTPS at the webservice level or at the proxy level?

Tags: nginx, security, web-server, https

These days I had to deploy several web apps, like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) or [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/). These apps *must* be served through HTTPS.

I was wondering if it's better to configure HTTPS on each app (listening port, ssl certificates, etc.) or to run the default configuration and force HTTPS with a reverse proxy like [nginx](http://nginx.org/).

I feel that the second solution is more practical, but maybe I'm missing something from the security point of view.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your deployment environment, but I would argue "TLS on all the things" is best practice. You can use internal or self-signed certs on the web services that are trusted by your proxy, and then a single "real" cert on the proxy that talks to the world.

If you have a protected network, in a protected datacenter, with no possibility of snooping, then doing HTTPS only to the outside world and unencrypted HTTP internally might be okay. Note these criteria specifically *exclude* anything like AWS or shared hosting providers where you don't have your own dedicated protected network infrastructure.

With [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) now in public beta, certificate installation is free, automated, and easy. So just do TLS on everything, and redirect plain HTTP calls into HTTPS.

Comment: lol, we gave nearly identical answers, eccept i forgot about Let's enrypt :-)

Answer (score 0):

Choice one seems more secure at a first glance, but it depends.

I would prefer the second one (See later for security implications), it's easier to secure the termination in one central place and on security the more complicated a solution is the more it's likely to get something wrong.

Caveats,

- you can have the proxy in the same machine as your apps, in this case both solutions have the same security implication.
- Different machines, let's say fe1 is the proxy and be1 is where the applications live. In this case you can choose to trust the fe1 -> be1 link or not, and if you choose not to trust that link you can use self signed or company wise internal CA emitted certs, so you dont have to pay for the certificates and decide duration and trust based on your internal policies.

I would go with SSL/TLS termination done at the proxy usually.